# Memory Leak in Solr cloud 4.8.1 and Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a solr cloud instance version 4.8.1 with 8 nodes, 4 shards and facing memory leak on the JVMs

here are the details of the instance.

1. 8 nodes, 4 shards(2 nodes per shard)
2. each node having about 55 GB of Data, in total there is 450 million documents in the collection. so the document size is not huge,
3. The schema has 42 fields, it gets reloaded every 15 mins with about 50,000 documents. Now we have primary Key for the index, so when there are any duplicates the document gets re-written.
4. The GC policy is CMS, with heap size min and max = 8 gb and perm size = 512 mb and RAM on the VM is 24 gb.

when users start searching(about 50 concurrent users) in solr and not always but often the heap keeps growing and the GC cycles are not clearing up the heap. I see GC running for almost 100,000 ms with still not clearing up the heap. There is definitely memory leak happening here.

Looking at the Heap Dump taken when the JVM heap size was at 99.9 %, I see org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl taking up a lot of memory 7.13 GB(out of 7.5 GB heap), it has a shallow size of just 32 Bytes, but referencing a Lot of HashMap and WeakHashMap objects and looks like its a singleton, but could not find a reason why its doing that.
Posting here to find out if anyone has faced memory leak with solr cloud with large volumes of data and if it could be remediated by configuration changes.

Comment: You should post this on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) instead, as I believe it is more suitable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that lucene field cache will be used by sorting and faceting operations, and if sorting is a mandatory use case then the solution is to define fields with [docValue](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues)(as shown below) attribute for sorting data.

```
<field name="test_field" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true" />
```

docValues are not supported on text fields and with tokenizers, so in this case I defined a new field of type `solr.StrField` and used it for sorting operation.

This eliminated the very high usage of Cache and Java Heap memory with out having to compromise any functionality.